# Is this possible? Last few digits of sum equal to another number

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers

I have a n-digit number and a list of numbers, from which any number can be used any number of times.

Taking numbers from the list, how do I know that it is possible to generate a sum such that the last n-digits of the sum are the the n-digit number?

**Note**: The sum has some initial value, its not zero.

**EDIT** - If a solution exists, I need to find the minimum number of the numbers added to get a number such that it has the last 4 digits as the given number. That be easily solved with DP (minimum coin change problem).

For example, if n=4,

```
Given number  = 1212
Initial value = 5234
List = [1023, 101, 1]
A solution exists: 21212 = 5234 + 1023*15 + 101*6 + 1*27
```

Comment: always possible? obviously not. sum=11, numbers: 2,4. initial value=2

Comment: Simpler counterexample would be sum = 1, numbers = [2], initial value = 0.

Comment: originally I wrote a simpler one, but I wanted to make sure that the OP doesn't complain about small details (only one number, sum is smaller than the numbers, initial value is zero, etc...)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't know how I missed that. Given these values, how can I check for the existence of such a sum and find it?

Comment: If you ask this on math.stackexchange they can probably give you a solution based on linear algebra.  Modular arithmetic, linear independence, magic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to find a counterexample (see comments).

Now, for the solution here's a dynamic programming approach:

All arithmetic is modulo 10^n. For each value in the range 0 - 10^n-1 you need a flag whether it was found and you need a queue for the elements to be processed.

1. Push the initial value to the to-be-processed-list.
2. Get an element from the to-be-processed list. If empty, finished. No solution.
3. Try to add each number separately to this number. If it was already found, nothing to do. If sum is found, you've finished, there's a solution. If not, mark it as found and push it to the queue.
4. Goto 2

An actual solution can be reconstructed if you store how you reached a number. You just have to walk back from sum till you hit the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

If the greatest common factor of the numbers in the list is a unit modulo 10<sup>n</sup> (that is, not divisible by 2 or 5) you can solve the problem for any choice of the other given values: use the extended Euclid's algorithm to find a linear combination of the list that sums to the gcf, find the multiplicative inverse of the gcf modulo 10<sup>n</sup> and multiply by the difference between the given and the initial values.

If the gcf of the numbers in the list is divisible by 2 or 5 (that is, is not a unit) and the difference between the given and the initial value is also divisible by 2 or 5, divide the numbers in the list and the difference by the largest powers of 2 and 5 that divide them all. If the gcf you end up with is a unit there is a solution and you can find it with the procedure above. Otherwise there is no solution.

For example, given 16 and initial value for the sum 5, and list of numbers [3].

The gcf of the numbers in the list is 3 which is a unit. Its inverse modulo 100 is 67 (3×67 = 201).

Multiplying by the difference between the given number and the initial value 16-5 = 11 we get the factor 67*11 = 737 for 3. Since we're working modulo 100 that's the same as 37.

Checking the result: 5 + 37×3 = 16. Yep, that works.